# How to show a rectangular image in Circle view?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to show a rectangle image with android compose in a circle shape but the edges don't stretch to fill the whole.
In other words I don't want the black background shown in the image below to appear and the flag to stretch to cover it even if I have to crop from the vertical edges
[image]

The code used to produce the image

```kotlin
Image(
  imageVector = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.flag_cn),
  modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize().clip(CircleShape)
              .background(shape = CircleShape, color = Color.Black))
```

**Update:**
 I tried to set the content scale option in Image Compose to crop

```kotlin
  Image(
            imageVector = vectorResource(id = flagID),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(0.4f)
                .background(shape = CircleShape, color = Color.Black)
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
val imageVector = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.flag_cn)
Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(200.dp),
        shape = CircleShape,
    ) {
        Image(imageVector, modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scale type option available for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of its view. This option is available for `ImageView`.

You can choose

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Reference:
[ImageView ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType)

Comment: there is no scale type in Image composable function there is contentScale which is similar and it's showing the same result

Answer (score 0):

Apply the [**`clip`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#clip) Modifier using a **`CircleShape`**:

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.xxx),
    contentDescription = "xxxx",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,            
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(64.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)                       
)
```

[image]